# Convert any Scala object to JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using latest version of Play Framework and it's JSON lib like this `Json.toJson(obj)`. But toJson is not capable of converting any Scala object to JSON, because the structure of data is unknown. Someone suggested using case convert, but here my Scala knowledge falls short. The data comes from database, but the structure of table is not known.

Where should I look further to create convert such unknown data structure to JSON?

Comment: How about using `Format[T]` (see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) You would have to know the type of `T` at compile time though, from the question I'm not sure if that would be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I checked the Format[T] option, but it seems that I need to know the structure of data in case to use it. But when I convert result from database to Map, the structure is [String,Any] - so basically unknown.

Comment: I mapped the data with ``asMap`` to the format ``[String,Any]``, but when trying to convert such structure with ``toJson``, Scala throws error – ``No Json serializer found for type List[scala.collection.Map[String,Any]]``

Comment: If the `Any` part is limited to some types like `String`, `Int`,...  pattern matching and explicitly converting those types could work. You'll need a `case`-line for every type you want to serialize though.

Comment: Yep, it is limited to some types. This is exactly what I had in mind. Could you give me some example, how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that there is only a limited number of types you want to serialize to JSON, this should work:

```
object MyWriter {
  implicit val anyValWriter = Writes[Any] (a => a match {
    case v:String => Json.toJson(v)
    case v:Int => Json.toJson(v)
    case v:Any => Json.toJson(v.toString)
    // or, if you don't care about the value
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("unserializeable type") 
  })
}
```

You can use it by then by importing the implicit value at the point where you want to serialize your `Any`:

```
import MyWriter.anyValWriter
val a: Any = "Foo"
Json.toJson(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect solution. How would you catch any value that is not String or Int? It could be casted to String or ignored at all.

Comment: Thanks! There is another problem now, that List and Map gets converted to string. The end result in JSON is literally this string ``"List(Map(users.id -> 1, users.status -> 1))"``

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add `case`-lines for all types you want to serialize, including collections like `List` and `Map`. That's why this approach is only viable if you have a limited number of types you want to support.

Comment: Yep, it wouldn't be a big problem because there is just a List and Map. I tried to add ``List`` like this ``case v: List => Json.toJson(v)``, but it didn't work because ``Error: type List takes type parameters``. Also is it possible to use this anyValWriter only for specific part of the dataset, where the type matching is actually needed, basically to avoid the List and Map part?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem mentioned in my previous comment. I used JsArray and JsObject to avoid Json.toJson on Map and List. Now it works, but I don't know if that is a proper way to do that.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the general question. I have an object and I have no idea what it is. I know that it's very complicated with lots of fields, lists, maps and nested objects inside. I don't care. I just want all of it in JSON like in c# or java

Answer (score 2):

Using json4s, you can import the package:

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write
```

Then create an implicit variable inside your trait:

```
implicit val formats: DefaultFormats = DefaultFormats
```

And finally, in your method, use it:

```
write(myObject)
```