# Scala object to Json with Play API

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I need to handle a case that hasn't been answered by this question: [Convert any Scala object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985098/convert-any-scala-object-to-json)

Basically, I don't know how to handle List and Map types. I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
implicit val anyValWriter = Writes[Any] (a =>
  a match {
    case v: Double => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Float => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Long => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Int => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: String => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Iterable[Any] => Json.toJson(v.map(t => Json.toJson(t)).toList)
    case v: Map[String, Any] => JsObject(v.map { case (k, v) => (k, Json.toJson(v)) }.toList)
    // or, if you don't care about the value
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Type not serializable.")
})
```

The resulting error is: `No Json serializer found for type Any. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

Trying to add `anyValWriter` to `Json.toJson` results in: `recursive value anyValWriter needs type`

Any idea?

Comment: Evil is in the `Any` for me. JSON API won't be able to find out how to properly encode Scala value according its type, as there is specifically no type (`Any`).

Comment: but why don't we have a concrete type here instead of Any ?

Comment: Please don't do this. It's completely at odds with the way Play JSON handles encoding and decoding.

Comment: For me issue is 'upper' than there. The app should not be in a situation of having to encode an `Any` value. Value to be encoded should have a known type, then JSON `Writes` can be resolved properly.

Comment: I have to handle an underlying API which returns Map[String, Any]. I'm really stuck with this evil type (Scala compiler already warned me)

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted my problem out through a workaround. I've chosen not to handle `Iterable` & `Map` types in the `Writes[Any]` and I used a wrapper to handle both types as in my case `Any` won't be an occurrence of either `List[...]` or `Map[String, Any]`.

Here's the code for those who are interested:

```
implicit val anyValWriter = Writes[Any] (a =>
  a match {
    case v: Double => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Float => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Long => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Int => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: String => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: JsArray => v
    // or, if you don't care about the value
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Type not serializable.")
})
```

And the wrapper:

```
  def convertToJsonValue(v : Iterable[Map[String, Any]])(implicit write: Writes[Any]) = {
    JsArray(v.map(t => JsObject(t.map {
      case (k, value) => (k, Json.toJson(value)(write)) }.toList)).toList)
  }
```

I'll find out later if I can sort out the ugly `JsArray` case.

PS: I know it's wrong but I'm using a SQL API which returns Map[String, Any] as I don't know the columns that will be returned (and I have good reasons for this and to not use the ORM feature).

Comment: Having typed data from DB doesn't require to use ORM.

Comment: I can't believe you downvoted me dude... If I want to handle typed data, I need to know how the resultset will be. Therefore I need to know in advance the columns I'll be getting from the query. This is exactly the same principle as specifying classes for an ORM, a matter of knowing in advance the types of the resultset (that I don't know, except that I'll have Strings and Numeric types). I didn't know it was correct to downvote an answer that helped me especially as I set the constraints (for which you don't have anything to say dude)