# io.circe encoder for java.lang.Object in scala

Tags: scala, circe

How to encode `java.lang.Object` using `io.circe`

Basically I am trying encode a `Map`

```
Map(
   "key" -> Option[Json].map(_.asObject).getOrElse(Map.empty) // `object[a -> "x",b -> "y",c -> "z"]`
   )
```

For e.g. I want to convert `object[a -> "x",b -> "y",c -> "z"]`  to `{"a":"x", "b":"y","c": "z"}`

Comment: What is `object[a -> "x",b -> "y",c -> "z"]`? That is not valid syntax nor the default `String` representation of any object I know. - Anyways, no **circe** won't encode an arbitrary `java.lang.Object` since **circe** derives the mapping logic at compile time, not a runtime.

Comment: perhaps this might help for an arbitrary json of unknown structure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985098/convert-any-scala-object-to-json

Comment: Circe has built-in support for `Map` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/RDHoKHMZTq6SsSblhLvMmg/1 Could you be more specific what you want to achieve?